# Async calls to service in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In my project I am calling same service for more than 2-3 times for finding distance & time for my route in javascript using cloudmode service.

I am having one polyline, I am getting each point of polyline & passing two consecutive points to service to get response from it.

What I am doing is

```
function showPointsRoutes(e)
        {
            var a = e.target.getLatLngs();
            for(var i = 1 ; i < a.length ; i++)
            {
             var as ="http://routes.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/api/0.3/" + a[i-1].lat+","+a[i-1].lng+","+a[i].lat+","+a[i].lng + "/car/shortest.js?callback=getRouteResponse";
             addScript(as);
            }
        }


    function getRouteResponse(response) 
      {
        mytimeArray.push[response.route_summary.total_time];
        myDistancArray.push[response.route_summary.total_distance];
      }

     function addScript(url) 
      {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type="text/javascript";
            script.src=url;
            document.getElementsByTagName('head') [0].appendChild(script);
        }
```

But sometimes what happens is that response for some requests comes late.
due to this I am not getting proper times & distance between points.
Can any one suggest some way so that I get values in array as sequence in which request was made.

Comment: You could specify transit points, then you only do one request, see here: http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/routing-http-api/examples/find-route

Comment: I dont have any transit points between these two points.

Comment: Then use @Dark Falcon solution, seems working for me

Comment: It is not working for me. Same thing is happening. Some times response comes late so values gets shuffled for points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they give you different callback names is so that you can differentiate requests by using a different callback for each one. Try something like this:

Note: @Rodrigo Assis's suggestion would be better in this case since the API supports this. Code below demonstrates a way to handle this when the API forces using multiple requests.

```
function showPointsRoutes(e)
{
  var a = e.target.getLatLngs();
  for(var i = 1 ; i < a.length ; i++)
    requestRoute(i, a[i-1], a[i]);
}

function requestRoute(i, a, b)
{
  window["getRouteResponse" + i] = function(response)
  {
    mytimeArray[i] = response.route_summary.total_time;
    myDistancArray[i] = response.route_summary.total_distance;
  };

  var as ="http://routes.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/api/0.3/" + a.lat+","+a.lng+","+b.lat+","+b.lng + "/car/shortest.js?callback=getRouteResponse" + i;
  addScript(as);
}

function addScript(url) 
{
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type="text/javascript";
  script.src=url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head') [0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: same thing happens. Some times response comes late so values gets shuffled.

Comment: That is not possible if you used the code I posted. Each response is put at its own index which directly corresponds to the index of the source data. The problem must lie in code you have not posted.

Comment: I got it.Problem is when I am trying to display it, I was trying to display it directly from getRouteResponse function, due to that I was getting wrong order.

Comment: @RodrigoAssis please give jsfiddle link

Comment: If you see your example, if you add more than 3 points then you will see that while displaying order changes.

Comment: @vaibhavshah Yes the displaying order depends on the api, you have no control over that, but you can wait till' all request are done to use then, see updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/knoxzin1/tVVZD/7/